# Generalized differential geometry based on Penrose's abstract tensor systems?

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, ct.category-theory, tensor-calculus

[Penrose graphical notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_graphical_notation) has been an important precursor of [string diagrams for monoidal categories](https://arxiv.org/abs/0908.3347). It was introduced in Penrose's paper [Applications of negative dimensional tensors](https://www.mscs.dal.ca/%7Eselinger/papers/graphical-bib/public/Penrose-applications-of-negative-dimensional-tensors.pdf) with intended use in differential geometry.

In modern language, his definition of *abstract tensor system* [has been related to](https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.3586) traced symmetric monoidal categories, but for Penrose's original purposes it seems better to work with a compact closed category enriched in vector spaces and whose underlying monoid of objects is $(\mathbb{N},+)$. Now string diagrams have been used in all sorts of ways since Penrose, but I have hardly seen any use in differential geometry since Penrose. Hence my question:

> Has anyone attempted to develop a synthetic generalization of differential geometry based on abstract tensor systems, or similarly on a suitable type of monoidal category in which the morphisms play the role of tensors on the manifold? Where can I read about this?

Of course, an obvious challenge here is to talk about Lie brackets and Lie derivatives in terms of the category, and to state and prove the existence and uniqueness of the Levi-Civita connection. I have some ideas for how to go about this, but they seem obvious enough that I'd first like to see what has been done already.